# Visual Studio 2010 and ODP.NET error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can someone please guide me to fix this problem while accessing "Server Explorer" ? I've tried reinstalling VS 2010 but no luck.

[image]

**Version of ODP.NET and VS2010**,

[image]

**Activity Log,**

```
OracleVSGPkg.Close - Exception when terminating Oracle Developer Tools SQL*Plus Service Oracle.VsDevTools Unable to load DLL 'oravs11w.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at Oracle.VsDevTools.OracleSVCSqlplus.Terminate() at Oracle.VsDevTools.OracleVSGPkg.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.Close() {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}
```

**Another re-installation, here is the log,**

```
317  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools Oracle Input Output Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.549 
318  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools Oracle Database Project Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.550 
319  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools Oracle Message Box Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.551 
320  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools Common Language Runtime Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.552 
321  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools PL/SQL Language Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.553 
322  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools SQL Language Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.554 
323  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Revoking Oracle Developer Tools Package Service {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.555 
324  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Remove the Oracle Developer Tools as an IOleCommand Target {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.556 
325  OracleVSGPkg.Close - Cleanup the Oracle Developer Tools Global resources {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.557 
326  OracleVSGPkg.Close - End Oracle Developer Tools VS Package Close {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.558 
327 ERROR End package load [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET] {D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio 2011/04/27 07:04:14.559
```

Comment: What version of VS 2010? What version of Oracle Developer Tools? Looking at the ODT download page, the link at the bottom says "download version 11.2.0.1.2 NEW! Supports VS 2010!"

Comment: I ran into a problem with an Oracle driver recently, but it was a BadImageFormatException - due to VS2010 running some things in 32Bit mode and unable to load the 64bit Oracle assembly.

Comment: The message box explicitly tells you what to do.

Comment: @Hans: OK, tell me what to do? I uninstalled ODP.NET. Now which version is good to go with Windows 7 64x ? I've already tried reinstalling couple of times.

Comment: Read the message.  It doesn't say "uninstall ODP.NET".  Nobody can help you if you don't explain why you cannot follow the instructions.

Comment: @Hans,I've ran VS in command line with\log parameter and it looks version problem to me. What ODP.net version is compatible with Windows 7 64x ? I've tried 11.2 and it doesn't work.

Comment: It's like pulling teeth.  Post the content of the log.xml file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post but I have just come across this exact problem when uninstalling the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client beta.

If you follow the instructions shown in your screen shot, i.e.

Make sure have have ran the Oracle Universal Uninstaller (OUI).

Open a devenv instance with

```
devenv /log
```

Once the instance has loaded close it down and go to.

```
C:\Users\{yourUser}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\
```

And look for the ActivityLog.xml file closest to your current time. And Open it.

```
C:\Users\c20082\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
```

Look for an entry similar to the following

```
  <entry>
    <record>288</record>
    <time>2013/07/18 07:56:02.183</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio]     </description>
    <guid>{D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}</guid>
  </entry>
```

Search your registry for this key and delete any entries referencing it.

Reinstall Oracle Developer Tools, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue many times. Actually reinstall ODT package is an alternative but very annoying. Hence I solved in this way, just reregistering the dlls in question.

1. Open Visual Studio 2010 command prompt **as administrator**.
2. Execute `devenv.exe /log`. Open the log to certify wich version is used. In my case, for instance, is **Oracle.VsDevTools.10.0**.
3. At the same prompt opened priorly, execute these two lines:

   ***gacutil /i {oracle home where you installed ODAC         11.2.0.2.1}\odt\vs2010\Oracle.VsDevTools.dll***

   ***gacutil /i {oracle home where you installed ODAC         11.2.0.2.1}\odt\vs2010\Oracle.Management.Omo.dll***
4. Open your Visual Studio 2010 and go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio. As you can see, the package was loaded successfully.

[image]